# TypoScript: get page title by page id

Tags: title, typo3, typoscript

Task1. In **TypoScript** I need to get a page **title** for a given page id `{$my_page_uid}`
Task2. This page title should be recieved according to the current language

I need this title in the form like *temp.pTitle*, so I can make then
    page.10 < temp.pTitle

Comment: Just to get updated: Are any of these answers working for you?

Comment: If one of the answers below works for you, would you please consider you accepting it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers What's the advantage of accepting an answer? It helps you and others: 1. Others will see that your question has an accepted answer and it will no longer show up in "unanswered" queue. 2. Others see at a glance, that there is an answer that works at least for one person. 3. You get a reputation increase of +2 Of course you should only accept an answer if it does work for you and answers the question.

Answer (score 18):

At a first glance I thought: Haha! That's trivial... but actually *it's not*. Here is a clever solution for the first part I found in a [german forum](http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/98814/):

```
temp.pTitle = HMENU
temp.pTitle {
  special = list
  special.value = {$my_page_uid}
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Don't know if this solves the language part, but it should.

Comment: Why would you do it as HMENU? Because of the language requirement?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you could just use `data = DB : pages : {$my_page_uid} : title`

Comment: Was my preferred solution so far. Nevertheless it stopped working in TYPO3 10 (or 9) when you want to get the title of a sysfolder. Will try a different solution.

Comment: Make sure to add "includeNotInMenu = 1" if you want to get the page title of a page that's not visible in menus normally ... :)

Answer (score 15):

```
temp.pTitle = TEXT
temp.pTitle.data = DB:pages:{$my_page_uid}:title
```

Comment: This one is IMHO the most exact solution!

Comment: @lorenz I noticed this too, how do I get the localized version with this?

Comment: For localized solution better use Matengs answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
lib.pagetitle = RECORDS
lib.pagetitle {
  source.data = page:uid
tables = pages
conf.pages = TEXT
conf.pages.field = nav_title
}
```

To get current page title:

```
lib.pagetitle = TEXT
lib.pagetitle.field=title
```

Comment: Thx, RECORDS will also work in TYPO3 10 with properties from a sysfolder .

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler solution..

```
10 = TYPOLINK
10.parameter = [your_page_id]
```

When you omit the .value or .field, it automatically takes the page title as value. This even works with multiple languages.

**Important note:** This answer was valid in 2011, TypoScript has obviously changed since…

Comment: There is no "doNotLinkit" Property in stdWrap.

Comment: There is no TYPOLINK cObject. [Content Objects (cObject)](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Index.html#)

Comment: This answer was valid for older versions of TYPO3 / TypoScript and was made in 2011. No need to downvote because it is wrong now (7 years later)...

Answer (score 0):

I made such a script and work without VHS functions: v.page.info (on TYPO3 v9):

Examples:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pageInfo" data="{pageUid: '48', pageField: 'subtitle'}" />

lib.pageInfo = COA  
lib.pageInfo {
    5 = LOAD_REGISTER
    5 {
        ## Set the content's field (default: title):
        pageField.cObject = TEXT
        pageField.cObject {
            field = pageField
            ifEmpty.data = title
        }

        ## Allows to override the current page ID:
        pageUid.cObject = TEXT
        pageUid.cObject {
            field = pageUid
            ifEmpty.data = TSFE:id
        }
    }

    20 = RECORDS
    20 {
        source.data = register:pageUid
        tables = pages
        dontCheckPid = 1
        conf.pages = TEXT
        conf.pages.field.data = register:pageField
    }

    90 = RESTORE_REGISTER }
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

In your fluid template

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.pagetitle" data='your page id'/>
```

In Typoscript

```
lib.pagetitle = HMENU
lib.pagetitle {
special = list
special.value.current = 1
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
    NO {
        doNotLinkIt = 1
    }
}
}
```

Let me know it this not working I have other ways!!